# File Structure and URL in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, url

Problem Question:

Currently I am learning AngularJs and when I launch my app on localhost, I see my URL as such

```
http://localhost:9000/public/index.html#/login
```

Is there a way to get rid of index.html from the url? . I want to have the same url as of production, so I know everything is working. I want my url to be something like

```
http://localhost:9000/login
```

My Directory structure is

```
App Name 
  --public
    --src
      --modules
    --index.html
    --app.js
```

Is this something that can be done on localhost?

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't look like an angularjs issue.  Which container or framework are you using to deploy with in production?  Is it the same as what you are doing locally?  Sounds like there may be some configuration in production that tells your server where to resolve your index page - which you may be missing.

Comment: Yup, i Know its not Angular problem, just wanted to know way to avoid index.html in Url. Also wanted advice on placing index.html to a correct place. Thanks

Comment: <a href="login">login</a>